# Mapping IOKit IOReturn error code to String

Tags: objective-c, iokit

When I get error 0x10, I want to be able to make sense of that error code. Looking up IOReturn.h and mach/error.h is not particularly convenient. I was lost when I got 0x22 error code. This is really silly question but is there a function like error2String which can map IOReturn error code to String that describes the error ?

Comment: So, what was error code 0x10? (I'm experiencing it right now.) Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

You can use the mach_error_string standard foundation function to do this.

Eg.  in Swift:

```
func krToString (_ kr: kern_return_t) -> String {
    if let cStr = mach_error_string(kr) {
        return String (cString: cStr)
    } else {
        return "Unknown kernel error \(kr)"
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this isn't more highly voted. Much cleaner than a massive lookup table

Comment: I agree with @genghiskhan, this is the best solution! The function is declared in `mach/mach_error.h`.

Answer (score 2):

Code running in the kernel can use `IOService::stringFromReturn(...)`

Comment: The documentation definitely suggests this is the way to go...but I have absolutely no understanding of how to invoke this from my code. All I get is "symbol not found" errors. What do I need to link against? Import/include? Thanks very much.

Comment: Is your code a kernel extension, or a user-mode application / library? IOService::stringFromReturn(...) is (unfortunately) only available to code running in the kernel.